# How to set Wordpress Featured thumbnail to fixed width and auto height

Tags: wordpress, function, thumbnails

I want to change post featured thumbnail to 1300px width and auto height since I don't want to crop the images, but nothing I do isn't working. At first the code was like this

```
add_image_size('discussion_post_feature_image', 1300);
```

I saw some answers here and tried it like this but didn't work

```
add_image_size('discussion_post_feature_image', 1300, 9999, false);
```

Is there any other way so I can upscale the image to that width but to not change the height? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to crop the image, instead of passing `false`, you shouls pass `true` in like-- `add_image_size('discussion_post_feature_image', 1300, 9999, true);`

And that should do.

Comment: No, I don't want to crop the image, i just want it to fit in the header of the post which is width 1300, but i cant set width without writing height also which results in cropping the image, since some images are landscapes and some are portraits, and i dont want to crop the portraits, i just want for all of them to fit with width

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you must have added the thumbnail support. You can use the following code in functions.php to add the support

```
function wpsm_setup_theme() {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   add_image_size( 'discussion_post_feature_image', 1300, 9999, true );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpsm_setup_theme' );
```

and to display the image:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail("discussion_post_feature_image");
}else{
 echo "No thumbnail";
}
```